# Call namespace from variable

Tags: php, namespaces, instance

I need to make a dynamic namespace: `[module]\controller\[controller]Controller`, but the follow code does not work:

```
$namespace = '\Account\Controller\LoginController()';
new $namespace;
```

Like this:

```
new \Account\Controller\LoginController();
```

What I forgot?

Comment: Try losing the `()` in the string.  `$namespace = '\Account\Controller\LoginController';
new $namespace;`

Comment: @Rocket worked fine, but, if I need to send params? `new \Account\Controller\LoginController($params);`? I will need the `()`. Unique solution is `call_user_func`, so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the `()` to the string.  The `()` are used when calling the function, not in its name.

```
$namespace = '\Account\Controller\LoginController';
new $namespace;
```

If you want to pass params, add the `()` to the `new` call.

```
$namespace = '\Account\Controller\LoginController';
new $namespace('abc');
```